# Get root path doesn't work, (html,php,.htaccess)

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, path

Im working on **mysite** and I have a login page **mysite/login**

In **login** I have styles working fine from href="./assets/css/login.css"

When I change the URL bar from "mysite/login" to "mysite/login/" (with the final "/") the styles stop working unless I change the href to **../assets/css/login.css**

I also have the htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /mysite

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

I tried writing

```
href="/assets/css/login.css"
href=<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?>"/assets/css/login.css"
```

but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: with mysite/login only the **href="./assets/css/login.css"** works

with mysite/login/ only the **href="../assets/css/login.css"** works

Comment: Does `mysite` exist as an actual folder in your site's root?

Comment: the folder "mysite" is the root, inside i have index.php, .htaccess and more folders (assets,views,models,controllers and config)

Comment: Ignoring all link tags and whatnot, can you directly access the resources? `https://YOUR_SITE/assets/css/login.css`

Comment: `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is a _file system_ path, it makes little sense to try and use that as a _URL. Just use `/assets/css/login.css` to refer to your CSS (no leading dot) - the trailing slash means relative to the domain, so it will not matter any more at what actual path depth you are with your main document.

Answer (score 0):

In code we use the / but in the file explorer it is \ I had a similar problem once I just replaced the / with \ .

Comment: I just tried href="\assets\css\login.css"
but the css it still didn't recognoized login.css :c